# Advantech DAQ set DO high and low in C#

Tags: c#, io

I have a Advantech 4750 USB DAQ.

I want to do what I did in the *navigator* in code (setting the digital output from low to high, and low again):

[image]

**How can I do this in C# using VisualStudio & how do I establish connection to the USB module in C#?**

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some kind of SDK Library (.dll) for .NET. This either implements the low-level code for communicating with the USB device, or it wraps some lower level C or C++ library that can communicate with the USB device. Or it might be a managed C++ dll.

**Looking at their website it was most likely included with that application you're using.**

You might find the SDK dll somewhere in the install directory that came with that GUI application you're using. Look around for a 'lib' or 'sdk' directory in the install folder.
You might find something if you search through that application's help menus, or look in its install directory for a readme/manual or look online for its manual.

This might be helpful:
https://support.advantech.com/support/DownloadSRDetail_New.aspx?SR_ID=1-1QPD6M3&Doc_Source=Download